# What use do people find from getting the visitors ISP from geolocation services?

Tags: data-mining, business-intelligence

I know the question borders between something that can be answered or discussed, but with just examples should be enough.

I'm working on BI and part of the data contained is the ISP from visitors. I'm trying to extract as much information from the data in the dataware, so I just wanted to know how I can help transform this specific piece of data into something valuable to the client.

Any samples of the value of knowing the ISP? The site I'm working for is massive (can't say which one), so that should block responses as "it would matter if you were `<giant-company>`". I need exactly THAT info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways I have used that information in the past is to determine what peering agreements are appropriate. That is, if you determine that 40% of users are coming from ISP X, then getting a peering arrangement setup with ISP X will improve user experience due to decreased latency. I've also used this information for selecting a CDN (pick the CDN that provides the best footprint for the ISP's your users are on). It could also be useful for determining where to put edge caches (for instance, varnish instances). There are a whole host of uses for the data but at the top of my mind the class of uses are limited to performance and availability.

Comment: I'm sure that, as you said, there's other cases, but this was a very useful and specific answer. Thank you!